# Asking for basic Query syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

- **Table A:**

> ```
> Order_Date   Order_Amt   Order_Cnt
> 06/01/13        50.00        2
> 06/02/13        30.00        1
> ```

- **Table B:**

> ```
> Waiver_Date   Waiver_Amt   Waiver_Cnt
> 06/01/13        25.00        1
> 06/05/13        15.00        1
> ```

I simply want the query syntax to produce the following result (merge records with the same date into one row, retain unmatched rows with null placeholders) :

- **Query Result:**

> ```
> Report_Date   Order_Amt   Order_Cnt     Waiver_Amt     Waiver_Cnt
> 06/01/13        50.00        2             25.00          1
> 06/02/13        30.00        1              null         null
> 06/05/13        null        null           15.00          1
> ```

I'm so drawing a blank on how to merge Order_date and Waiver_date into one Report_date.  I'm sure this is a no-brainer for someone out there!

Thanks in advance! K.

Comment: Is there any way to put an ID into these tables?  Would make this query a WHOLE lot more simple.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a full outer join. If the join column had the same name in both tables, the "merge Order_date and Waiver_date into one Report_date"-part of your question would simply go away:

```
SELECT Report_date, Order_amt, Order_Cnt, Waiver_Amt, Waiver_Cnt
  FROM tableA FULL OUTER JOIN tableB USING (Report_date)
```

As the columns are named differently, you need the `On`-syntax and merge both columns for instance wiht `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Order_date, Waiver_date) AS Report_Date, Order_amt, Order_Cnt, Waiver_Amt, Waiver_Cnt
  FROM tableA FULL OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.Order_Date = tableB.Waiver_Date
```

Now, if your SQL dialect lacks a full outer join, you can model it with an union of a left outer and a right outer join:

```
SELECT order_date AS Report_Date, Order_amt, Order_Cnt, Waiver_Amt, Waiver_Cnt
  FROM tableA LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.Order_Date = tableB.Waiver_Date
UNION 
SELECT Waiver_date AS Report_Date, Order_amt, Order_Cnt, Waiver_Amt, Waiver_Cnt
  FROM tableA RIGHT OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.Order_Date = tableB.Waiver_Date
```

Comment: I never knew about full outer join!  Great to learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

Assume you use MySQL. You can use [`JOIN`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)s to combine columns with a common value:

```
SELECT Order_Date AS Report_Date, Order_Amt, Order_Cnt, Waiver_Amt, Waiver_Cnt
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON Order_Date = Waiver_Date
  UNION
SELECT Order_Date AS Report_Date, Order_Amt, Order_Cnt, Waiver_Amt, Waiver_Cnt
FROM A RIGHT JOIN B ON Order_Date = Waiver_Date;
```

Checkout the [**demo here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b74955/5).

If your database supports full outer join (e.g. PostgreSQL), this following also works:

```
SELECT Order_Date AS Report_Date, Order_Amt, Order_Cnt, Waiver_Amt, Waiver_Cnt
FROM A OUTER JOIN B ON Order_Date = Waiver_Date;
```

Comment: This would only return a single row in his example.

Comment: @Scottie Sorry, should be an `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: You'd still need the IsNull(a.Order_Date, b.WaiverDate) AS ReportDate

Comment: @Scottie I don't need that.

Comment: Yang:  I used your union query above with one small change in the second select "select waiver_date as report_date...".  Thank you, this works perfectly! I also discovered the beauty of sqlfiddle.com from your answer.  Thank you @Scottie for your input as well.

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated your table structure in Sql Server and this appears to work:

```
SELECT IsNull(A.Order_Date, B.Waiver_Date) AS Report_Date, Order_Amt, Order_Cnt,  Waiver_Amt, Waiver_Cnt
FROM B
RIGHT JOIN A ON A.Order_Date=B.Waiver_Date
UNION
SELECT IsNull(A.Order_Date, B.Waiver_Date) AS Report_Date, Order_Amt, Order_Cnt,  Waiver_Amt, Waiver_Cnt
FROM A
RIGHT JOIN B ON A.Order_Date=B.Waiver_Date
```